# C# - Acesso Negado Arquivos Windows

Tags: c#

Olá estou a fazer um software capaz de escanear determinados arquivos do Windows, onde nele deixo filtrados certos tipos de extensões, porém, ao colocar para escanear da a seguinte mensagem de acesso negado em determinadas pastas.

O código seria o seguinte:

```
DirectoryInfo dir_Local = new DirectoryInfo(tb_UnidadeHD.Text);

string[] extensao = new string[] { "*.WsF", "*.lnk", "*.vbs", "*.vbe", "*.js", "*.com" };
string[] dir_Info = Directory.GetFiles(tb_UnidadeHD.Text, extensao.ToString(), SearchOption.AllDirectories); ;            

try
{
    foreach (string procura in dir_Info)
    {
        lb_Arquivos.Text = string.Format("Escaneando: {0}", procura);
        string result = ScanForVirus(procura);

        if (!dir_Local.Exists)
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Diretório de origem não existe ou não pôde ser encontrado: {0}", dir_Local), "AlegoTools", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        else
        {
            if (result != string.Empty)
                listBox_Files.Items.Add(result);                            
            else
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Não foi encontrado nenhum vírus em {0}", dir_Local), "AlegoTools", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
}
catch { }
```

Se poderem me dar uma luz, pois tentei outros meios mas sem sucesso, ele simplesmente nao consegue escanear certas partes do windows, mesmo estando como admin, mostra como se estivesse sem acesso pelo programa, e ele estã configurado para executar como administrador

Comment: Colocar um `catch` vazio é a última coisa que deveria fazer. Você não colocou a mensagem. Preciso sair, depois eu vejo se dá pra responder.

Comment: "da a seguinte mensagem de acesso negado em determinadas pastas." você chegou a observar o erro no debug? em minha resposta estou deduzindo que seja a exceção  [UnauthorizedAccessException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.unauthorizedaccessexception(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: A questao nao seria o catch vazio, pois, ja utilizei a exceção do UnauthorizedAccessException e o erro seria o mesmo.

Answer (score 2):

Aparentemente e só um problema de permissão de pasta, você pode tentar verificar as permissões acessando as propriedades na guia segurança você pode verificar permissões da pasta.

**Exemplo**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Tratando a exceção**

Como o usuário não tem acesso o jeito e notificar ele sobre sua permissão e se for o caso permita o acesso para ele a pasta desejada.

**Código**

```
catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
{
  MessageBox.Show("No Momento Você Não Tem permissões para realizar esta operação , Contate o Administrador Do Sistema  ! Detalhes : " + ex.Message, "Alerta ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
}
```

Comment: Não teria como dar permissão, pois o aplicativo é para fazer varredura em varias máquinas, e fica dificil ter que dar permissão maquina por maquina, até são varias pastas que dao o erro de acesso negado, ja cheguei a dar permissao em algumas, mas sao varias que dão tal problema. Queria ver se tinha alguma opção de forçar ele a ler tal pastas.

Comment: Nesse caso você deve reformular a pergunta afinal seu objetivo e forçar a leitura dos diretórios e não tratar um erro , mas infelizmente neste caso não sei te dizer se isso e possível .

Comment: Isso, seria forçar a ler os diretórios, porém mesmo o nível de acesso como admin geral ainda não obtém o acesso mesmo ate colocando para ignorar as partes em que obtém o erro de nível de permissão.